# MySQL 8.0.13 Group Replication Recovery Error MY-002061

Tags: mysql, mysql-group-replication

I have MySQL group replication with 3 servers. One of them experienced an error and was unable to recover its ONLINE status in the replication list due to an error connecting to a donor server.

> [Repl] Slave I/O for channel 'group_replication_recovery': error
>   connecting to master 'repl@PRIV_IP_HERE:3306' - retry-time: 60 
>   retries: 1, Error_code: MY-002061

I re-initialized group replication on all 3 servers. Bootstrapping the replication list on the first server worked, but neither of the other 2 servers were able to join the group successfully (stuck in RECOVERING state).

How can I fix this group replication recovery process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MY-002061 is an authentication error.

MySQL requires that any caching_sha2_password (auth type on your replication user) is protected by TLS or RSA.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html

> To connect to the server using an account that authenticates with the
>   caching_sha2_password plugin, you must use either a secure connection
>   or an unencrypted connection that supports password exchange using an
>   RSA key pair, as described later in this section.

If your network is secure, the most convenient way to solve this problem is to create a MYSQL RSA keypair:

```
mysql_ssl_rsa_setup
```

Then update your MYSQL config on each server to request the public key of the donor server during group replication recovery (instead of storing a local copy of the trusted public key which is a bit more work but prevents MITM attacks):

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
...
group_replication_recovery_get_public_key = 1
...
```

Then reload your MYSQL process and reattempt group replication:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql reload

mysql> START GROUP_REPLICATION;
```

Worked for me, 2018-12-07.

Additional reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Also see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-options.html#sysvar_group_replication_recovery_get_public_key